# CheckBox UserControl Always Checked

Tags: wpf, checkbox, user-controls, mainwindow

I have a usercontrol called RateView.xaml.cs. This user control contains a checkbox called CheckBox1.
I put this user control on my MainWindow 5 times. I need three of the usercontrol's on the MainWindow to have the checkbox on from the start of the app. How can this be accomplished?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) `IsChecked` on the `UserControl`, [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) it to the *internal* `CheckBox`, set that property accordingly on the instances of the `UserControl`.